# Tag synonym request: ([kernighan-and-ritchie] and [kr-c]) -> [knr]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

[kernighan-and-ritchie](/questions/tagged/kernighan-and-ritchie) - 15 questions

[kr-c](/questions/tagged/kr-c) - 25 questions

[knr](/questions/tagged/knr) - 29 questions

I suggest we merge [kernighan-and-ritchie](/questions/tagged/kernighan-and-ritchie) -> [knr](/questions/tagged/knr) and [kr-c](/questions/tagged/kr-c) -> [knr](/questions/tagged/knr).

Rationale: [knr](/questions/tagged/knr) seems to be the most popular tag, and I believe these tags all mean the same thing. [knr](/questions/tagged/knr) is just an abbreviated form of [kernighan-and-ritchie](/questions/tagged/kernighan-and-ritchie), and all questions tagged [knr](/questions/tagged/knr) are also tagged [c](/questions/tagged/c), so [kr-c](/questions/tagged/kr-c) seems redundant. Also note that all questions tagged [kr-c](/questions/tagged/kr-c) are also tagged [c](/questions/tagged/c) as well, and some are tagged [knr](/questions/tagged/knr) too.

Comment: Given that knr does not have a tag wiki and most people will not know that it means, I don't think it is a good merge target.

Comment: @Ian good point about the wiki... I was going to write an excerpt for [knr] but didn't want to duplicate the excerpt across the various tags, so I got sidetracked...

Comment: How about [kernighan-and-ritchie-c] or [k-and-r-c]?  IMO, it's perfectly OK to have 'c' in the tag - See the examples of [tag:c89], [tag:c99], and [tag:c1x].

Comment: @Kevin Are you suggesting those as merge targets? I wouldn't mind [k-and-r-c]. And FWIW, [c89], [c99], and [c1x] seem to be directly related to C and would be meaningless without C in their names, so I agree that it's okay there. The way I see it, the meaning for any of the K&R tags is the same and refers to the famous book *The C Programming Language*, with or without a C in the tag. If the community feels that we need to throw a C in the merge target, that's fine with me-- let's just get a synonym here.

Comment: Yes, I was.  Given that the tags don't have wikis, I assumed that the tags referred to the version of the language, like these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3092006, http://stackoverflow.com/q/1542023, http://stackoverflow.com/q/1466521 - But, on further investigation, you're right - Most of the questions are about the book.  Perhaps we need two tags, one for the book and one for the language?  I agree that *something* needs to happen.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for those examples, I had overlooked that it was also possible to use it to differentiate from ANSI C. So there indeed are two distinct meanings, then.

Comment: Here's another vote for `knr` being the merge target.  It has a tag wiki now.

Comment: Googling "knr" doesn't give very good C-related results, "and" doesn't start with an "n", and I'd never seen K&R abbreviated that way before I saw that tag. This still needs some kind of synonym/merge action, though, 2 years later.

Comment: @Wooble ""and" doesn't start with an "n", " - tell that to [these guys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guns_N%27_Roses)

Comment: @AakashM: granted, "and" is often contracted to "'n'". I'm just not convinced it's commonly done with Kernighan 'n' Ritchie. Although I suppose people saying "K&R" fast may sound like they're saying "KNR". Still seems like a stretch to use it as a tag name. It's probably telling that searching Google for "KNR C" asks if you meant "K&R C" :)